# Why is the scientific community, and especially the astrophysicists, so skeptical about sterile neutrinos?

Tags: astrophysics, standard-model, neutrinos, dark-matter

As rob pointed out in a comment in my previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719477/charged-fermions-have-both-chiralities-with-the-same-mass-shouldn-t-neutrinos) :

"There were hints about sterile or missing neutrinos in LSND, in the low-statistics region of MiniBoone, and in a number of other neutrino results, but the community was rightly skeptical."

Sounds quite true.  But why “rightly skeptical” ?

More recently, the [BEST](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14654) experiment results shows serious arguments for the existence of one sterile neutrino in the eV/c^2 mass range.

But this has not produced much excitement in the astrophysical community, in particular with respect to the possibility of sterile neutrinos as Dark Mater candidates.

**Please** don’t belabour the obvious and shower me with arguments that  eV/c^2 mass range sterile neutrinos are useless in astrophysics. I can do elementary arithmetics, thanks.

But there are three families of fermions. Including three ordinary neutrinos. Would not the most natural extension of the Standard Model to accommodate neutrino masses consist in introducing **three** sterile neutrinos ? If the lightest is in the eV/c^2 mass range couldn’t either the intermediate mass one, or the heaviest one be an interesting candidate for Dark Matter ?

Very roughly, mass ratios for second to first, and third to second families are

- for 2/3 charge quarks  500 and 150
- for -1/3 charge quarks 40 and 20
- for charged leptons  200 and 20

Since for usual neutrinos only mass **differences** can be obtained from neutrino oscillations data the ratio from second to first cannot be known. However, assuming that the first is not **very** close to the second one can guesstimate the mass to the second one to be reasonably close to  $\sqrt{\Delta m^2_{12}}$, and the mass of the third one to be close to $\sqrt{\Delta m^2_{23}}$, leading to a ratio “third to second” of the order of 5.

So these ratios vary a lot and one cannot make an estimate of the mass of the second and third sterile neutrinos if they really exist, except that they are significantly heavier than the lightest one.

But doesn’t il look promising ?

Also, the three eigenstates of neutrino mass (1, 2, and 3 just above) do **not** coincide with the there neutrino “flavors”, electronic, $\mu$-onic and $\tau$-onic. There is a rather complicated $3\times 3$ matrix relating them.

If the masses of the neutrinos, ordinary **and** sterile, come from a see-saw mechanism, wouldn’t it stand to reason than their masses would come from the diagonalisation of a $6\times 6$ matrix ?
In which case the argument against “reasonable mass” sterile neutrinos, namely that that the heaviest mass should be in the GUT range (because the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace, and the trace is predicted in the GUT range) fails for a $6\times 6$ matrix. Indeed **just one** super-heavy sterile neutrino is needed to take care of the bulk of the trace of the matrix, leaving two others. The lightest one, the one found in BEST, in the eV/c^2 range, and the intermediate one that can have any mass whatsoever ! In particular, an astrophysical interesting mass, in the keV/c^2 range,  for a Dark Matter candidate.

Why hasn’t anyone yet jumped on such an attractive possibility ?
(Dont count me, I am retired, and my field was **not** astrophysics anyway, it is just a “hobby” for me)

---

Edit : I have read the paper suggested by anna v in her comment below.

This paper predates the results of the BEST experiment, but mentions older results as well as the "gallium anomaly" which is the very point of BEST.

The author did consider the $6\times 6$ matrix I have suggested above. But for some reason he considers only the cas of one reasonably light sterile neutrino and **two** very heavy ones. But with now solid (if not yet **conclusive**) evidence for one sterile neutrino in the eV/c^2 mass range and the need of another one in the keV/c^2 mass range to account for (tepid) Dark Matter, is there any proposal in the direction of the $6\times 6$ matrix having **only one** very heavy eigenvalue ?

Comment: relevant article https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.05913

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterile_neutrino#Sterile_neutrinos_as_dark_matter  "From what is known about the particle thus far, the sterile neutrino is a promising dark matter candidate, but, as with every other proposed dark matter particle, it has yet to be confirmed to exist. "

Comment: @anna v  OK, thank you. You gave me a lot of reading material. This paper is too old to know about the latest BEST results, but is does refer to the gallium anomaly, so it is "almost" up to date.

Comment: I think one part of the skepticism comes from the fact that different experiments claiming evidence for sterile neutrino, see not the same thing and sometimes contradict to what other experiments find. See the recent overview at a neutrino workshop: https://indico.fnal.gov/event/53004/contributions/246274/. (Disclaimer: I am not a neutrino physicist.)